# web-safe fonts in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, web-safe-fonts

I need to adapt the style of a flex app to the style a given HTML/JS/CSS Web App. One problem I faced is the Font ‘Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif’. How can I set such rare Fonts in Flex?

Comment: Verdana and Geneva are not 'rare'.

Answer (score 1):

Embed the font(s) in your compiled code. That way you don't have to rely on them being present on the client machine.

More info:

- [flex 3.x](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=fonts_04.html)
- [flex 4.x](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f5f.html)

Comment: My question is about rare fonts like the mentioned one. I found various Verdana ttf fonts in the Net, but none was sans-serif and Geneva. Is it possible to get the selected browser font (e.g. ‘Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif’) from somewhere such that it can be replicated in Flex? In general: How to replicate Browser fonts in Flex? Is the mentioned Font available separately for Flex at all?